# Go back to current debug line in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

While debugging Java in Netbeans you set up a break point and inspect variables and execute step by step, etc.

However, once the program is paused you often check other parts of the code. 
Is there any shortcut or menu item to return back the screen to the source code and line where the program is halted?

Not sure if relevant but I am using both Netbeans 8.2 and 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When debugging you have a Debug window with the tabs "Variables", "Call Stack" and "Breakpoints".

To go back to the source line of the current break point, open the "Call Stack" tab. Then right click on the top most entry of the stack and choose "Goto source".

If you don't have the "Call Stack" tab, you can open it using the menu item "Window -> Debugging -> Call Stack"